# How to use before and after in tailwind css?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

```
.card {
  position: relative;
  background-color: grey;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 90px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: calc(50vh - 30px) auto 0 auto;
}

.card::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
  top: -5px;
  width: calc(100% - 25px);
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  border-top: 5px solid brown;
  border-left: 5px solid brown;
}

.card::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  right: 10px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```
<div class="card">
</div>
```

I am not able to understand how to create the same thing using tailwind

I tried with tailwind but it is not working, I watch youtube video and also search for how to use after and before in tailwind , I am new to tailwind

Answer (score 7):

You can set before and after element styles by adding `before:` and `after:` respectively in front of a tailwind class.

```html
<a class="text-sky-400 after:content-['Hello\_World'] after:text-red-500" ...
```

read more here:
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#before-and-after

Answer (score 1):

Use the content-{value} utilities along with the before and after variant modifiers to set the contents of the ::before and ::after pseudo-elements. Out of the box, content-none is the only available preconfigured content utility.

Answer (score -1):

class="relative mx-auto mt-20 h-9 w-9 bg-black before:absolute before:h-10 before:w-10 before:bg-blue-300">

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).